# stop propagation from child to parent jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not seeing something obvious here? I've seen dozens of solutions for similar problems, but they didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
  $(".init-tutorial").on("click", function(e){
    var template = $(".pointer.template");
    var posX = e.pageX - $(this).position().left - 8,
      posY = e.pageY - $(this).position().top - 8;    

    template
      .clone() 
      .removeClass("template")
      .css({"top":posY,"left":posX}).attr("tabindex",-1)
      .appendTo($(this)).focus();
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".comments", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Problem is that .template appended (which contains .comments) propagates all clicks to the parent el, which is undesirable.

Only way I was able to stop it was using `if (e.target === this)` - but this causes another set of problems for me, as I've multiple elements which SHOULD receive event.

template markup:

```
<div class="pointer template" style="">
  <div class="comments">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="კომენტარი"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">დაპოსტე</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

regarding container div, it is nothing special

```
<div class="init-tutorial" style="height:400px;width:400px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

jsfidle : http://jsfiddle.net/9cjrp079/

Comment: Can you provide the markup? Without markup we cannot determine how the code should or should not work.

Comment: @Terry markup provided, I will create a quick jsfiddle now.

Comment: @Terry http://jsfiddle.net/9cjrp079/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".comments", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

IMO, when this code is triggered, the event has already been propagated to the `$(document)`.
You may have to attach the onclick listener directly to `$(".comments")` but not `$(document)`.

E.g.

```
$(".comments").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

---EDIT---

set the `.click` for each appended element:

```
template
  .clone()
  .removeClass("template")
  .css({"top":posY,"left":posX}).attr("tabindex",-1)
  .appendTo($(this))
  .focus()
  .click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cjrp079/1/

Comment: that doesn't work either, as .comments doesn't exist, it is appended via on click on parent.